# Groupby in column with condition to return boolean?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe,

```
     equipment      value      loc
0       ac1         43.2       acs_blg
1       ac2         23.1       acs_blg
2       ac3         0.0        acs_blg
3       ac4         44.4       acs_blg
4       kz1         12.1       qet_blg
5       kz2         87.2       qet_blg
6       kz3         65.3       qet_blg
7       yy1         0.0        cna_blg
8       uu1         55.3       ppp_blg
9       uu2         0.0        ppp_blg
```

If one of the equipment at a loc has value 0, then I should get a boolean false otherwise if the all the equipment has value more than 0, then it should return true. I am quite sure groupby will need to be use to group the loc.

End result

```
     loc        boolean
0    acs_blg    false
1    qet_blg    true
2    cna_blg    false
3    ppp_blg    false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) with [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) here.

```
df.groupby('loc')['value'].all() # Thanks to YOBEN_S for pointing this.
#df.groupby('loc')['value'].apply(pd.Series.all)

loc
acs_blg    False
cna_blg    False
ppp_blg    False
qet_blg     True
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

To retain the order set `sort` parameter of groupby to `False`.

```
df.groupby('loc',sort=False)['value'].all()

loc
acs_blg    False
qet_blg     True
cna_blg    False
ppp_blg    False
Name: value, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Make it outside apply `df.groupby('loc')['value'].all()
` apply is time cost function ~